# Crontab executes task every minute instead of running it once

Tags: cron

I have the following crontab record:

```
* 17 * * 5 /usr/share/app/bin/run.sh
```

I expect it to run every Friday at 17.00, but looks like the task is executed first at 17.00 and then approximately every minute till 18.00

What is wrong here?

Comment: Hi svz -- would you kindly click the check mark to accept my answer? Thanks!

Comment: I think this question belongs to Super User.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * is a wildcard, use

```
00 17 * * 5 /usr/share/app/bin/run.sh
```

It makes sense that

```
*  17 * * 5 /usr/share/app/bin/run.sh
```

runs every minute until 18:00 b/c `* 17` keeps matching.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Would've taken much time to figure that out.

Comment: No pb! Glad that worked. (If you haven't yet, pls mark this as answered ;-)

Comment: Is that so? I didn't know that. You've answered a question I didn't know to ask ;-)  Cheers